# Length-Value encoding

Tags: encode

I have a homework question. I do not understand the example given. Because how can a byte be 255 bytes?
I thought that, because of this example, the answer to (a) is 510 bytes, and the answer of (b) is 128. But yeah, i am confused..
Can someone maybe explain this one?

An alternative encoding scheme is Length-Value encoding, where each string is encoded as
a sequence of two elements:
 L: a fixed length value that specifies the length of the string in bytes
 V: the string itself
The length of L, however, limits the maximum length of V. For example if L is a byte V
cannot be longer than 255 bytes.
Knowing this limitation, how many values can be injectively encoded using LV encoding
(a) if the length is encoded using 2 bytes?
(b) if the length is encoded using Length-Value encoding with length of 4 bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not saying that a byte is 255 bytes. It is saying that **V** (the string being encoded) cannot be longer than 255 bytes, if its length (L) is specified by a single byte 2^8 (0-255). If you used more two bytes you would be able to specify strings up to 2^16 (0-65535) characters long.

For example, if we wanted to encode the value `Example`. We would write its length (L) and then the value (V). I.e. we would write `7` as a byte followed by the bytes for the ASCII values of the characters in the word `'E'`, `'x'`, `'a'`, `'m'`, `'p'`, `'l'`, `'e'`. If we only use a byte for the length then we cannot encode a very long string because a byte's range is 0-255 or 1-256 (256 = 2^8) because a byte only contains 8 bits.

The answers it wants are (a) (2^16 - 1) = **65535** and (b) (2^4 - 1) = **15**.

However, the question is mistaken that the maximum length is 255. It should be 256, unless you want to be able to specify zero length strings.